# Crystal Report - text colour change

Tags: crystal-reports, conditional-formatting, crystal-reports-2008

I am using a formula field that has a description text (string object).
I would like to change the font colour if the description of the text contains partial value.
eg. Brisbane Exhibition Centre - if the description has "Exhibition"word then colour should be red.

The intention is to highlight a text that has a specific word, this is similar when we do this in excel in conditioning formula "Text that contains "and chagne colour to RED.

Kind Regards,
Mudit

I tried changing field with adding formula using like operator but did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the formula field, ***Format Field***..., select ***Font*** tab and select the button to set an expression for the **Color** property. For example:

```
IF instr(CurrentFieldValue, "Exhibition")> 0 Then crRed
Else IF  instr(CurrentFieldValue, "Conference") > 0 Then crRed
Else crBlack
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that given solution worked, apologies for late update. Regards, Mudit.